# OpenCV + Eclipse on Linux - Build issues

Tags: c++, eclipse, opencv, eclipse-cdt

I downloaded opencv from [here](http://opencv.org/releases.html) and extracted it to `/home/XXXX/Documents/opencv-4.4.0`.
I want to link it to Eclipse. So I did this -

In the project settings -> GCC C++ Compiler -> include path I gave `/home/XXXX/Documents/opencv-4.4.0`.

Then in the linker section I added the libraries and set the library search path to `/home/XXXX/Documents/opencv-4.4.0` and even `/home/XXXX/Documents/opencv-4.4.0/include`.

When I build the project, I get this error -

```
18:50:10 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project displayImage ****
make all 
Building file: ../src/displayIMage.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -I/home/XXXX/Documents/opencv-4.4.0 -I/home/XXXX/Documents/opencv-4.4.0/include -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/displayIMage.d" -MT"src/displayIMage.o" -o "src/displayIMage.o" "../src/displayIMage.cpp"
In file included from ../src/displayIMage.cpp:1:
/home/XXXX/Documents/opencv-4.4.0/include/opencv2/opencv.hpp:48:10: fatal error: opencv2/opencv_modules.hpp: No such file or directory
   48 | #include "opencv2/opencv_modules.hpp"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [src/subdir.mk:20: src/displayIMage.o] Error 1
"make all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.
```

I followed everything according to [this](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d16/tutorial_linux_eclipse.html) tutorial. I tried running `pkg-config --cflags opencv` to find the right paths but that gave me this error -

```
Package opencv was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `opencv.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'opencv' found
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You added the `include` folder to the linker path?

Comment: If you look at the guide you link you need to set: include paths as weel. In you case you need to add `/home/XXXX/Documents/opencv-4.4.0/include` to the include path not the lib path

Comment: and the reason pkg-config cannot find opencv is because it is not in your lib/include path